# String attribute value as boolean expression

Tags: java

I have a requirement to evaluate certain logic based on certain condition. This condition is defined in a column in DB which can be modified at any time in future.

This condition can be used as if condition expression. Can anybody suggest? For example -

```
 String condition = resultSet.getString("column"); 
//can have a value such as g.equalIgnoreCase("0") || g.equalIgnoreCase("0")
if (condition) {
//Some code here
}
```

Comment: I use beanShell library.  This post has many suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Comment: try using regex patterns for condition evaluations